# Add two hours to the current time stamp

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following syntax :

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $modtime = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( $today ) + (2*60 * 60));
```

I want to add two hours to the current time stamp , but I keep on getting the current time stamp from the above syntax. How can I make it pick the timestamp + 2 hours?

Comment: rather pointless to convert the current time to a string, convert it BACK to an int, and then back to a string. why not just `date(..., time() + 7200)`?

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](http://3v4l.org/1062d)

Comment: Your code should work, are you sure you "echo" the right variable? [Look](http://ideone.com/e57hVD)

Answer (score 6):

you can add 2 hours like this

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
strtotime('+2 hours', strtotime( $today ));
```

you can use `strtotime('+2 hours')`. default second parameter is `time()` today's timestamp.

[check manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: uh, why not just `strtotime('+2 hours')`? very wasteful to take "now", convert to a string, convert BACK to an int, and then into a string yet again.

Comment: In this particular case, `time()+2*60*60` is probably just as good. But the original code should work.